# How to customize GUI in Jhipster+ React application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jhipster, jhipster-registry, jhipster-gateway

I have created an application with jhipster + react. It's a default application generated by jHipster. We need to customize the GUI according to our needs(ex, Background change, alignment, layout,menu) on jhipster home page. Do we need to edit it manually in the code or any configurations available for GUI change in react?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: you must modify the generated code manually.

Alternatively, if you plan to have several projects, you could write a [JHipster blueprint](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/) but this requires more effort.

Comment: Thanks, @Gael Marziou